# Как решить проблему execComand('copy') на IOS?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ios

Суть проблемы: при нажатии на кнопку на сайте должно происходить копирование какой-либо информации, которая располагается где-либо на сайте, в моем случае в `data-attr`. Копирование везде, кроме `IOS` можно легко сделать при помощи `execCommand('copy')`. То есть мы создаем какой-то скрытый `input` или `textarea`, в ней выполняем `select()`, а дальше `execCommand('copy')`. C IOS все неочевидно. Stackoverflow предлагает решение через userAgent

```
const iosFlag = !!navigator.userAgent.match(/ipad|ipod|iphone/i);

copyClipBoard() {
 if (iosFlag) {
  const oldContentEditable = this.textArea.contentEditable;
  const oldReadOnly = this.textArea.readOnly;
  const range = document.createRange();

  this.textArea.contenteditable = true;
  this.textArea.readonly = false;
  range.selectNodeContents(this.textArea);

  const s = window.getSelection();

  s.removeAllRanges();
  s.addRange(range);

  this.textArea.setSelectionRange(0, 999999);
  this.textArea.contentEditable = oldContentEditable;
  this.textArea.readOnly = oldReadOnly;

  document.execCommand('copy');
 }
}
```

Решение рабочее, но проблема состоит в том, что на IOS происходит скролл страницы до того места, где создан инпут. ТО есть если я делаю `document.body.appendChild(myTetxtArea)`, то он скроллит прямо к этому элементу. Можно решить проблему создавая `textarea` прям под кнопкой копирования. Тогда скролл минимален (но он есть), при этом на доли секунды появляется клавиатура девайса и пропадает.

И, собственно, я не знаю, как решить проблему появления клавиатуры и микроскролла? Есть ли какие-то еще решения, чтобы копировать по кнопке, при этом на IOS было также визуально, как и везде?

Comment: К сожалению, не на чем сейчас поиграться. Похоже `input` получает `focus`, попробуйте копнуть в этом направлении.

Comment: @Qwerty_Wasd да, вы безусловно правы. Он получает фокус. Потому что если он его не получит, то не произойдет выделение. В этом вся суть. Спасибо, что откликнулись.

Comment: А если сразу после получения фокуса проскролить обратно? Теоретически такое заметно не должно быть. А вот как убрать клавиатуру. Попробовать сразу же после копирования снять фокус. Поскольку все это выполняется в одном цикле, то заметно для пользователя не должно быть.